# My .htaccess causes 'redirect error' in Google Search Console, or a bug?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having an issue with Google Search Console. It seems it can't redirect my pages properly, so in **Coverage** it returns some '*redirect errors*' when it shouldn't.

Let's say the link: https://example.com/name

Browsers redirect to: https://example.com/name/

Search Console cannot do that, because it shows a persistent '*redirect errors*'.

If we assume that it's a bug in Search Console, we would try to deindex pages that are not cannonical. What result we get? Now Search Console redirects to the canonincal one, so it deindexes the good one!!! My site is *Domain property*, where there are more '*redirect errors*'.

This is my .htaccess:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Remove www subdomain
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Remove index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>

# Remove multiple slashes from URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType font/otf otf
    AddType font/ttf ttf
    AddType font/woff woff
    AddType font/woff2 woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jp2                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf               "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript               "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                    "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</ifModule>

# Allow access from all domains for web fonts
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Header set Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

# Reduce MIME type security risks
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# Server-side technology information
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>

# Server software information
ServerSignature Off

# Disallow usage in an embed code. Items must be hyperlinked
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Frame-Options: DENY
</IfModule>

# XSS protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

# Set the referrer policy
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade "
</IfModule>

# This is for gzip, which compresses files
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Is there something wrong? Do I have too many redirects? Is it a Search Console bug? Please check my config.

The same happens with http URLs, returning an "error redirection" when it should find the https version.

My site is build with Jekyll.

Comment: I added the word "Google" to your question title and the question body in order to make it clear what you are talking about. The edits are currently under review. I hope that you are indeed talking about Google Search Console. If not, please edit your question and specify which Search Console you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Thanks!

Comment: "Now Search Console redirects to the canonincal one, so it deindexes the good one!!!" - what do you mean by this? What is the "canonical" URL? What is the "good" URL? Why are the two not the same? "My site is Domain property, where there are more 'redirect errors'" - What are the redirect errors specifically?

Comment: The good URL is the one that contains https, non-www, and ending with a slash /. If I type http://www.example.com/hello in a browser, it will redirect to https://example.com/hello/, and it's perfect, it's ok. However, in Google Search Console, section coverage, it's not making redirections, so it throws errors. If I try to deindex http://www.example.com/hello (to remove the error), it will deindex https://example.com/hello/. I'm not sure if I'm not explaining this correctly. The canonical is the redirected page (browsers do, GSC doesn't).

Comment: In summary, if I inspect a URL without the ending slash, or with the http, or with the www, Google Search Console is not making the redirection, so it returns a persistent error in Coverage section.